# Disable/enable button depending on text input

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple input type="text", two input type="password" boxes with class="important" and one checkbox. When all input with class important is filed and checkbox is checked the button should be enabled,else disabled. I have this script,but when i enter text in only last input it enables button. Can someone help?

`js`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".important").on('keyup blur change', function () {
        $(".important").each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().trim() == "") {
                $('#form-right input[type="submit"]').addClass('inactive');
            } else {
                $('#form-right input[type="submit"]').removeClass('inactive');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

`this is html:`

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label class="mandatory">Naziv agencije</label>
                <input class="important" type="text" name="naziv_agencije" id="register_agency">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="mandatory">Adresa</label>
                <input class="important" type="text" name="adresa" id="register_address">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="mandatory">Telefon 1</label>
                <input class="important" type="text" name="telefon_1" id="register_phone">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Telefon 2</label>
                <input type="text" name="telefon_2" id="register_phone2">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Fax</label>
                <input type="text" name="fax" id="register_fax">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="mandatory">E-mail</label>
                <input class="important" type="text" name="email" id="register_email">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Web adresa</label>
                <input type="text" name="web_adresa" id="register_web">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="mandatory">Korisničko ime</label>
                <input class="important" type="text" name="korisnicko_ime" id="register_user">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="mandatory">Lozinka</label>
                <input class="important" type="password" name="lozinka" id="register_pass">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="mandatory">Potvrdi lozinku</label>
                <input class="important" type="password" name="pot_lozinku" id="register_passr">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Logo</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="max_file_size">
                <input type="file" name="logo" id="register_browse">
                <label class="browse-button" id="register_browse">Izaberi logo</label>
                <label class="file-label" id="register_browse">Logo još nije izabran</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="checkset">
                    <div class="custom-true">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="pravila" id="register_terms">
                        <label>Da,slažem se sa <a href="html and css.pdf">previlima i uslovima korišćenja</a>

                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" name="register" value="registruj se" disabled="disabled" class="inactive">
            </li>
            <li>
                <p class="catalog">Cenovnik usluga iternet sajta <a href="/" title="Last Minute Ponude">Last Minute Ponude</a>
pogledajte <a href="/">ovde</a>
.</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: why not put the checking on the check box if all the input have value and the checkbox is checked enable if not dont.

Comment: That whould be god,but that means if you only check check box it will andable button.

Comment: check my fiddle below the updated one see if that is ok

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$(".important").each(function(){
    //...
});
```

is going to execute the logic it contains for each element.  Which basically translates to:

- If the first element has a value, enable the button
- If the second element has a value, enable the button
- etc.

So as long as the last (and only last) element has a value, the button will be enabled.  The check against any previous element is immediately overwritten by the next element.

The logic *should* be:

- If any element does not have a value, disable the button

A simple loop can accomplish that:

```
var elements = $(".important");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if($(elements[i]).val().trim() == "") {
        $('#form-right input[type="submit"]').addClass('inactive');
        return;
    }
}
$('#form-right input[type="submit"]').removeClass('inactive');
```

The idea here is to loop through the elements and look for any one which is empty.  As soon as an empty one is found, de-activate the button and return from the function.  (Since we don't need to check the rest of the elements.)  If no empty one is found and the loop completes, enable the button.

Comment: wow that was fast and educational. i aprisiate the lecture. I just need one more thing. the checkbox with id=register_terms should be checked too before enabeling button.

Answer (score 1):

***[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/20ntsgt4/)***

1. Added id to submit button.
2. Used the checkbox to check if input is not empty if complete check the checkbox if checked activate the button.

   $("#register_terms").on('change', function () {

   ```
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $(".important").each(function () {
           if ($(this).val().trim() == "") {
               $('#qwe').prop('disabled', true);
           } else {
               $('#qwe').prop('disabled', false);
           }
       });
   } else {
       $('#qwe').prop('disabled', true);
   }
   ```

   });

***[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/20ntsgt4/2/)***

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/20ntsgt4/4/)

Comment: That is what i need. Nice

Comment: Sorry but again i have same problem... if i only enter text in last input and check check box the button will be enabled.

Comment: @DejanJankov can you check this new fiddle\

Comment: how did it go?is it ok?

Comment: it wont work on my site... code that David posted works but its not the whole thing. this one is what i need,but cant make it work on my site.

Comment: function in your script is not closed becouse of that it wont work,but in fiddle it works  without closed function.

Comment: if ($(this).is(':checked'))  this is why it wont  work,but still can't figure out why.

Comment: I made it work for me... but i had to style it a bit and now i cant make it work perfectly. can you look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9rsddhk/2/) ?

Comment: I found a solution,but thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: have you checked the fiddle?@DejanJankov

Comment: Yes, that is what i need. Thank you again.

Comment: is this correct now?i hope it helped you one way or the other happy  coding

Comment: You helped me with this. Made me think different and made it easier to find answer i needed. Yes that is correct. Thanks again.